# Why the map values change even if they are not pointers - Golang

Tags: testing, go

I'm trying to test a method. Its signature is  `func (gv *myType) Update(all map[string][]SomeType) error`

Although the test fails (the expected value doesn't match the received value) I've found that also the map it receives(`allSub`) is "updated" after the method is evaluated. Here is the code:

```
t.Logf("allsub %v", allSub)
if err := gv.Update(allSub); err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
    return
}
if !reflect.DeepEqual(egv, gv) {
    t.Errorf("allSub %v", allSub)
    return
}
```

The output

```
mth_test.go:265: allsub map[b:[{1 3 3}] a:[{1 0 0} {1 2 0}]]
mth_test.go:271: allSub map[a:[{1 2 0}]]
```

As you can see on `t.Logf("allsub %v", allSub)` we have `map[b:[{1 3 3}] a:[{1 0 0} {1 2 0}]]` and then after the evaluation `if !reflect.DeepEqual(egv, gv)` allSub becomes `allSub map[a:[{1 2 0}]]`. This drives me crazy and I'm wondering how is this possible? allSub is not a pointer.

Comment: Show full, executable example. Just a guess: Your `Update` method modifies the map content (which is possible, even if you do **not** pass a pointer as maps and slices behave like "reference types").

Comment: @Volker that explains a lot and would make the answer. A link to the docs would be helpful. Although the specs are light I can't find any metion about that(e.g. on maps https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types ).

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#references . The description of map types in the spec is not overly verbose on this: It is just that map elements are just elements of the map and not the map itself, just like elements of a slice are just elements of the slice and not the slice itself. Thus the content of a map may change during execution like a the value of a slice element may change without the slice itself being changed.

Answer (score 0):

Map, slice, channels are reference types. The spec is in-process to become clearer about this but basically the implementation of these builtin types entails a reference to an underlying data structure.

So you can consider that an object of type `map` is actually a reference to an associative array.

Effective Go has a little paragraph on it :
https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps

I quote :

> Like slices, maps hold references to an underlying data structure. If you pass a map to a function that changes the contents of the map, the changes will be visible in the caller.